# Why do inactive chat rooms become "frozen"?

Tags: discussion, chat, frozen-rooms

I was having a discussion with someone in chat. I wasn't able to respond for a couple of weeks for various reasons. When I attempted to return to the conversation I discovered that it had become "frozen".

So now I'm wondering why this "freezing" feature even exists. What's the rationale behind it?

Comment: Preserving the generated conversation without getting in the way of the still active rooms?

Comment: You can still create a *new* room with the same person, and refer to the transcript from the frozen room.

Comment: @MartijnPieters How does freezing the room prevent it from "getting in the way of the still active rooms"?

Comment: The room list will does not list frozen rooms, you need use the 'show frozen / deleted rooms' button at the bottom to have those listed explicitly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So why is it impossible to unfreeze a frozen room?

Comment: because they are inactive

Comment: @KevinB pretty sure you missed the question date. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Rooms are frozen to stop cluttering up the active rooms, when it is unlikely participants are going to return. The transcript is still available and can be referred to.

Just open another room with the same user; you can find the user in the users tab of the chat site, and you'll find a 'create a room with' option there.

From the [chat FAQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention):

> Frozen rooms do not allow any new messages to be sent, and are not shown in the default room list to prevent cluttering the rooms interface.

A room is frozen if there were at least 15 messages by at least two users, but was otherwise inactive for 14 days. If the minimum users and messages criteria are not met, the room is *deleted* instead, after only 7 days.

If a specific room has more value to you than just the transcript, because, say, you shared the URL elsewhere and it'll be hard to change that, you can perhaps persuade a moderator to unfreeze it for you. You'll have to find yourself a moderator first, you cannot flag a chatroom, so look for a diamond user in another chatroom. Perhaps you'll find one in [Tavern on the Meta](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta).

Comment: Most of this answer isn't actually answering my question, which is "what is the rationale for freezing rooms", not "how do I work around it" or "when does it freeze them". I understand how it behaves, and I understand that there are workarounds. What I don't understand is *why it was designed such that these workarounds are even necessary*. To make an analogy, it's like SO was selling buckets, but they all have a hole in the bottom. I ask "why do all of thee buckets have a hole in the bottom?" and I'm told "you can plug the hole with your finger if you need to carry water."

Comment: The one part of your answer that somewhat addresses my question is the first sentence, but that doesn't explain why I can't unfreeze a room or why there isn't simply an "active" flag on rooms that is used for filtering from the active rooms list without preventing the possibility of ongoing conversation in the room. The latter seems like a much more obvious solution to the "active rooms list is getting cluttered" problem, so I'm curious to know why "frozen" was used instead.

Comment: I've given you what I know from public information. The rest would be mere speculation; we'd need the SE developers to weigh in on this. I'll look if there are pre-existing feature requests that ask for the ability to unfreeze a room (by the room owners, for example).

Comment: This doesn't explain the rationale for freezing chat rooms.  If the purpose is to avoid clutter, just hide the chat rooms; there's no need to block people from continuing the discussion.  Forcing people to start multiple chat rooms about *the same topic* just because their discussion is taking too long is nonsensical.

Comment: @endolith: That's why there is a [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208593/make-it-possible-for-normal-users-to-unfreeze-chat-rooms) for allowing owners to re-open a room.

Comment: Are rooms that were unfrozen by a moderator, still subject to the same inactivity rules? In other words, can they automatically be frozen again?

Comment: @Cerbrus: they are still subject to the same rules, a mod unfreezing doesn't keep a room unfrozen forever.

Comment: Someone please implement this already :P

Comment: Do you know why this room got deleted in 7 days, even though there was 15 message by at least 2 users? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113915/discussion-between-saismaran-s-b-pes1201701189pes-and-ruslan Maybe the messages that were originally "comments" on a main site post, do not count?

Comment: @user1271772 Yes, comments copied into a room on creation by a moderator do not count as activity here.

Comment: The room was not created by a moderator, it was created by clicking a link suggested by the system.

Comment: @user1271772: then too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If the messages that were comments on the original post, don't count, then why did [this room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112878/gpaw) last more than 7 days? You can see that it was inactive for 12 days at one point without closing, and you can see that all of the messages by xmV and Susi Lehtola were already in the original post on the main site.

Comment: @user1271772 chat room is deleted after 7 days only if there are no more than two users posting, when there are three or more, it's always 14 days, and not deletion but rather freezing.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I think the room requires at least 15 messages, and they need to be from at least 2 different users, for the room to last more than 7 days. With the room mentioned in my last comment, it seems that comments that were transferred from the main site counted towards the required 15; but in the room mentioned in the comment earlier than that, it seems that the comments from the main site didn't count. That's at least what seems to be the case almost 2 years after the comment-chain ended :)

Comment: @user1271772 "A room is considered worth retaining if it has more than 15 messages by at least 2 users" so yes you're correct, I never remember the exact numbers lol. Anyhow, the condition of "at least 15 messages" wasn't met, that's why the room in the first comment was deleted. It's "and", not "or", which can be made clearer in the faq.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I agree that it's "and" rather than "or". The protein folding room had [15 messages by 3 people](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55934478#55934478) then got deleted 7 days later. The GPAW room seems to have stayed open for more than 7 days despite apparently not having the required minimum of 15 messages, but weirdly the earliest message I can see in that room now is "This room has been automatically deleted for inactivity". Quite a harsh **first** message for a chat room! Deleted before anything even happens!

Comment: @user1271772 no. I counted manually. It had 10 messages from 3 users, so it was deleted 7 days after the last message. The "15 messages" from Nike was posted after the room was undeleted, it's visible [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55934423#55934423). There is no bug, no error, it works just as expected, for some reason something confused you along the way.

Comment: @user1271772 GPAW having first message the "deleted" looks weird, but it just means there was no message since the room was created. So it was created by someone, nothing was posted at all, hence it got deleted after 7 days. So, it would be good feature request to ask to add automated chat message "Room has been created" to make things more clear and less odd in such cases.